# Can I install an HttpModule (IIS) to activate only for specific VERBs?

Tags: c#, iis, webdav, httpmodule

Is there any way to specify that my HttpModule should only be invoked for specific VERBs? I only want to handle POST.

I've prefaced my event handler with:

```
try
{
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

    if (ctx.Request.RequestType == "POST")
    {
```

but I am still seeing a 500 on HEAD and OPTIONS requests. If I could set this up to only activate for POSTs then other verbs would process unimpeded. Full details are available here -

[HttpModule Extends WebDAV - Throwing 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052000/httpmodule-extends-webdav-throwing-500)

Short of solving that issue, if I could workaround it through configuration then my problem is solved.

Comment: The [HttpHandler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/307985/info-asp-net-http-modules-and-http-handlers-overview) is more fit to your task.

Comment: Hi Vladimir. POSTS to my site are to different 'folders' depending on the sender. For example: mysite.com/clientx/foldery or mysite.com/clienta/folderb. My processor intercepts these posts, validates them and then saves the contents to the appropriate location. Given that these posts aren't targeted to a specific page resource, it doesn't seem that I can use a Handler to do this. Am I missing something?